# chain promise.all with returned array from previous promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm writing my own blogging platform in node. I have a bunch of code that does the following:

1. Reads `.md` files from a bunch of folders, where each folder is the top level category.
2. Processes the data in each file, reading out data from the `YAML` front-matter and markdown-formatted text.
3. Sorts these by date, then writes a bunch of `.json` files, like this:

   - `cache/posts.json`
   - `cache/[category]/[category].json`
   - `cache/[category]/[post-id].json`, `cache/[category]/[post-id].json`, ..etc.

---

I have this working with a callback triangle of doom. Someone told me I should do this with promises, however, try as I might, I just can't get my code to work. So for, I have:

```
folders = ['notes','gallery','diary'];

function getFilesInFolder(folder) {
  //returns a new Promise that contains an array of markdown files
}

function getFileContents(folder,file) {
  //returns a new Promise that contains the data from the file
}

function processPostData(data,folder,file) {
  //returns a new Promise that contains a json object that I want to 
  //write out to a file
}

function processAllPosts() {
  Promise.all(folders.map(getFilesInFolder))
  .then((files,folder) => {
    console.log(files);
   })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('yuk, an error:',err);
   })
 }
```

What I can't get my head around is how to now call a new `Promise.all` for the returned array of files from `getFilesInFolder` and pass this to `getFileContents`.

I'm also doing this with array's `map` function, how would I pass in the current folder in, something like: `files.map(getFileContents(file,folder))` ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

Addition: I now have this code working. For anyone that might find it useful, it's [here](https://github.com/roobottom/roobottom-express/blob/8fd844488a5ace53d470d9433c0f5993fc75fda9/src/posts.promises.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These seem like sequential actions to me, rather than actions that can be run in parallel. You would use Promise.all to execute a series of async actions in parallel and wait for all the actions to complete before the next action.

I would chain your async actions, using map functions to transform the generated arrays:

```
function processAllPosts() {
 return getFilesInFolder.then(function(files){
    return Promise.map(files, function(file){
       return getFileContents(file)
    });
  })
  .then(function(fileContents)){
    return Promise.map(fileContents, function(content){
      return processPostData(content);
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('yuk, an error:',err);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is starting to make sense now. The other part I don't understand is how to pass multiple variables to a `.then` — for example, `getFilesInFolder` resolves both the `files` array and `folder` variable. How would I pass both of those on to `getFileContents`?

Comment: To be clear ,I'm now using a bastardised version of your code @tate-thurston which is probably madder than a box of frogs, [see it here](https://gist.github.com/roobottom/793e607032b62e6ff808)

Comment: No problem! You have a few options to accomplish what you want. You can't pass multiple values to your `then` because functions in javascript can only return a single value. You can return an array though. This would require you to adjust the function signature. The next option is to assign to outer variables that would remain in scope. That variable can then be used when you call your subsequent functions. The cleanest method would probably be to break the promise chain into parts. I can show you how to do that if you want to go that route.

Comment: Thanks again @Tate. I _think_ I'm doing a combination of the two things in my [latest solution](https://gist.github.com/roobottom/793e607032b62e6ff808) This seems to be returning a full list of posts now. I'm looping through each folder explicitly now, so the `folder` variable stays in scope throughout the whole event chain. I've also changed `getFileContents` to return an object that contains the `id` I use in the next part of the chain. I feel like I'm almost there with this, aside from node now telling me that I'm sending headers more than once. Does my code look OK to you?

Comment: Rather than taking a cb as a parameter, simply return the promise chain. That way your function returns a promise.